# Android Bluetooth Low Energy old sdk

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an old Android device using Gingerbread which is bluetooth low energy capable.

However when I try to build a BTLE app Android Studio complains saying that minimun SDK is 18 and I have 10.

I tried to avoid those problems using SuppressLint and I can compile the application but dalvik complains about linking the class.

Link of class 'Lcom/package/class;' failed

Is there any way to force dalvik to link my class even if I have an older Android device or to modify bluetooth low energy api so that it doesnt complain?

Any idea where does Android studio gets the information to know that BTLE api is only available from API > 18?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea where does Android studio gets the information to know that BTLE api is only available from API > 18?

Of course Android studio got the information from the SDK.

> Is there any way to force dalvik to link my class even if I have an
>   older Android device or to modify bluetooth low energy api so that it
>   doesnt complain?

Simply no way to force it working. The api just does not exist before API level 18. 
If by "modify bluetooth low energy api" you mean you will build your own version of Gingerbread with BLE support, you will have a extremely slim (or non-existent) chance to get it working. However please keep in mind that having a chip that supports BLE does not mean the device can use BLE.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to use BLE Android API with android API < 18? tricking it with NDK? or any other solution? The device does actually scan BLE devices. But I cannot achieve the same result with Java code.

Comment: @user3032175 What is the model of device? Is it rooted? What app are you using to scan BLE devices? Please add these information to the question.

Comment: It's a custom device and it is rooted I am using the system bluetooth tool to scan devices.We are using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonestreet_One bluetooth chipset